# Nonce token compromised

Tags: spring-security

We have mobile application which consumes backend services to complete the registration flow.

1. Our server is sitting in UAE, mobile user is from Vietnam
2. If the app user is connecting via Wifi - he is able to complete the registration
3. If the app user is connecting via his 4G Hotspot - he is unable to complete the registration as the call is ended up with 401.
4. We have enabled the debug log for our service and found below errors:

   ```
   2023-04-17 11:49:36 o.s.s.w.a.w.DigestAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Nonce token compromised 1681717779175:72d320b28d1db6461bae108db1b38c78
   2023-04-17 11:49:36 o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter [DEBUG] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@ff817d1
   2023-04-17 11:49:36 o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
   ```

What could cause this kind of issues?

We have compared the successful call nonce value and unsuccessful call nonce value. By decoding the nonce value to check if the nonce validity is expired (ie, 10 seconds). But both calls are having more than 10 seconds difference.